# Bitwise and between integers for permissions

Tags: php, mysql, bitwise-and

I have a database (mysql tinyint(3) unsigned) field and a bitmask for permission purpose.
For example:

```
$permission=(int)$db->pdo->query("select permission from user where id=1");
$rulemask=64;    
$hasPermission=$permission&$rulemask;
```

My question is... should I worry about that php integers or mysql numbers can be negative and this code can fail with high numbers due to two's complement?

Comment: Only if you start working with a lot of permissions.... on 32-bit PHP, you can have a limit of 31 permissions with this approach.... you keep track of it and your code logic ensures that $permission is correctly set to not exceed that value and always be positive

Comment: Sub-question: does php manage unsigned int?

Comment: Sub-answer - No http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php